# Entity Framework children collection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a table named "Notaries":

```
NotaryID int,
NotaryName nvarchar(MAX)
```

and table named "NotaryPhones":

```
PhoneID int,
NotaryID int,
PhoneNumber nvarchar(50)
```

So, relationship "one-to-many". Now I want to clear all phones, depending on the notary. My code:

```
            Notary.Models.Notary notary = (from i in db.Notaries where i.NotaryID == model.NotaryID.Value select i).FirstOrDefault();
            notary.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(model.City.SelectedItem);
            notary.NotaryPhones.Clear();
            db.SaveChanges();
```

but I get an error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

If I remove the string

```
notary.NotaryPhones.Clear();
```

it works. I understand, that this is a trivial thing, but don't understand how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on is that your `notary.NotaryPhones.Clear();` is removing the foreign-key reference from your `NotaryPhone` table to your `Notary` table. Because this is set up as a non-nullable key so that you don't have orphan phone records, you're receiving that error.

What you'll want to do instead is set up a method in your repository that will call `context.NotaryPhones.Remove(**instance variable pointing to one of the phones to delete**);` and that will delete them from the database.

**CLARIFICATION**

The reason why it removes the foreign key reference is that `notary.NotaryPhones.Clear()` just removes those objects from the `notary` object. The objects will continue to exist the way that you have written this.

So when the `.Clear()` is executed, it takes your `phone.NotaryID` property and gets rid of the ID pointer to the `notary`. Since you're not assigning it anything else, the value it tries to assign is `null` (the only value that couldn't possibly point to a `Notary` object). But, because you have it set up as an `int`, and not an `int?`, it can't make that assignment and it throws the error you see.

You said you're trying to delete the objects, so you need to remove them from the database. To do that, you do what I explained above.

Comment: You may find that `Delete()` comes from a third party library of extension methods.  The "out of the box" method `Remove()` is common.

Comment: nothing understand. Why removing the foreign-key reference? I remove all records in NotaryPhones table with NotaryID=X, right? Which field try to change to null value?

Comment: Thanks. I was 95% certain it was `Remove()`, but didn't want to get a question back later "I can't find `Remove()`?" when it was `Delete()`. I'll remove that part.

Comment: I'll elaborate above @OlegSh.

Answer (score 2):

please excuse the example if there are syntax errors, I am currently working in VB but the approach is the same

```
foreach (NotaryPhones np in notary.NotaryPhones)
{
      db.NotaryPhones.DeleteObject(np);
}
```

then save your changes with

db.SaveChanges();

Comment: thank you. But one note - collection will be modified after one operation and foreach will throw an exception. I found the other way to do it:                 db.NotaryPhones.RemoveRange(db.NotaryPhones);

Comment: Did you try it? You are modifying the db.context.NotaryPhones not notary.NotaryPhones. However, if you can use RemoveRange then that approach is probably more efficient.

Comment: sorry, db.NotaryPhones.RemoveRange(notary.NotaryPhones);

Answer (score 2):

`Clear` just removes entity from the related collection. it doesn't remove entity from database. you have to delete each `NotaryPhone` from corresponding `DbSet`.